# uWSGI fails with ModuleNotFoundError

Tags: django, docker, uwsgi

I have [this rep](https://github.com/paulobfsilva123/covidoff-web/tree/tracker) with a Django app and Docker, but `docker-compose up` is not working. This is my output:

```
Starting covidoff-web_db_1 ... done
Starting covidoff-web_webapp_1 ... done
Starting covidoff-web_webserver_1 ... done
Attaching to covidoff-web_db_1, covidoff-web_webapp_1, covidoff-web_webserver_1
db_1         | 2020-03-20 00:50:54.601 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on IPv4 address "0.0.0.0", port 5432
db_1         | 2020-03-20 00:50:54.601 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on IPv6 address "::", port 5432
webapp_1     | HOST: db:5432, DB: None, USER: postgres
db_1         | 2020-03-20 00:50:54.605 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on Unix socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"
webapp_1     | ==> Django setup, executing: flush
db_1         | 2020-03-20 00:50:54.620 UTC [24] LOG:  database system was interrupted; last known up at 2020-03-20 00:25:37 UTC
db_1         | 2020-03-20 00:50:54.802 UTC [24] LOG:  database system was not properly shut down; automatic recovery in progress
db_1         | 2020-03-20 00:50:54.804 UTC [24] LOG:  invalid record length at 0/16538C0: wanted 24, got 0
db_1         | 2020-03-20 00:50:54.804 UTC [24] LOG:  redo is not required
db_1         | 2020-03-20 00:50:54.817 UTC [1] LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections
webapp_1     | ==> Django setup, executing: migrate
webapp_1     | Operations to perform:
webapp_1     |   Apply all migrations: admin, announcements, auth, contenttypes, sessions, tracker
webapp_1     | Running migrations:
webapp_1     |   No migrations to apply.
webapp_1     | ==> Django setup, executing: collectstatic
webapp_1     | Skipping 'admin/fonts/README.txt' (not modified)
webapp_1     | Skipping 'admin/fonts/Roboto-Light-webfont.woff' (not modified)
webapp_1     | Skipping 'admin/fonts/Roboto-Regular-webfont.woff' (not modified)
webapp_1     | Skipping 'admin/fonts/LICENSE.txt' (not modified)
webapp_1     | Skipping 'admin/fonts/Roboto-Bold-webfont.woff' (not modified)
webapp_1     | Skipping 'admin/js/prepopulate.js' (not modified)
webapp_1     | Skipping 'admin/js/inlines.js' (not modified)
webapp_1     | Skipping 'admin/js/urlify.js' (not modified)
webapp_1     | Skipping 'admin/js/actions.min.js' (not modified)
webapp_1     | Skipping 'admin/js/autocomplete.js' (not modified)
webapp_1     | Skipping 'admin/js/cancel.js' (not modified)
webapp_1     | Skipping 'admin/js/actions.js' (not modified)
webapp_1     | Skipping 'admin/js/prepopulate.min.js' (not modified)
webapp_1     | Skipping 'admin/js/collapse.min.js' (not modified)
webapp_1     | Skipping 'admin/js/SelectBox.js' (not modified)
webapp_1     | Skipping 'admin/js/change_form.js' (not modified)
webapp_1     | Skipping 'admin/js/popup_response.js' (not modified)
webapp_1     | Skipping 'admin/js/jquery.init.js' (not modified)
webapp_1     | Skipping 'admin/js/prepopulate_init.js' (not modified)
webapp_1     | Skipping 'admin/js/core.js' (not modified)
webapp_1     | Skipping 'admin/js/inlines.min.js' (not modified)
webapp_1     | Skipping 'admin/js/collapse.js' (not modified)
webapp_1     | Skipping 'admin/js/calendar.js' (not modified)
webapp_1     | Skipping 'admin/js/SelectFilter2.js' (not modified)
webapp_1     | Skipping 'admin/js/vendor/jquery/jquery.min.js' (not modified)
webapp_1     | Skipping 'admin/js/vendor/jquery/LICENSE.txt' (not modified)
webapp_1     | Skipping 'admin/js/vendor/jquery/jquery.js' (not modified)
webapp_1     | Skipping 'admin/js/vendor/xregexp/xregexp.min.js' (not modified)
webapp_1     | Skipping 'admin/js/vendor/xregexp/xregexp.js' (not modified)
webapp_1     | Skipping 'admin/js/vendor/xregexp/LICENSE.txt' (not modified)
webapp_1     | Skipping 'admin/js/vendor/select2/select2.full.min.js' (not modified)
webapp_1     | Skipping 'admin/js/vendor/select2/select2.full.js' (not modified)
webapp_1     | Skipping 'admin/js/vendor/select2/LICENSE.md' (not modified)
webapp_1     | Skipping 'admin/js/vendor/select2/i18n/ko.js' (not modified)
webapp_1     | Skipping 'admin/js/vendor/select2/i18n/ms.js' (not modified)
webapp_1     | Skipping 'admin/js/vendor/select2/i18n/ca.js' (not modified)
webapp_1     | Skipping 'admin/js/vendor/select2/i18n/ja.js' (not modified)
webapp_1     | Skipping 'admin/js/vendor/select2/i18n/sv.js' (not modified)
webapp_1     | Skipping 'admin/js/vendor/select2/i18n/hi.js' (not modified)
webapp_1     | Skipping 'admin/js/vendor/select2/i18n/it.js' (not modified)
webapp_1     | Skipping 'admin/js/vendor/select2/i18n/da.js' (not modified)
webapp_1     | Skipping 'admin/js/vendor/select2/i18n/vi.js' (not modified)
webapp_1     | Skipping 'admin/js/vendor/select2/i18n/hy.js' (not modified)
webapp_1     | Skipping 'admin/js/vendor/select2/i18n/et.js' (not modified)
webapp_1     | Skipping 'admin/js/vendor/select2/i18n/eu.js' (not modified)
webapp_1     | Skipping 'admin/js/vendor/select2/i18n/fa.js' (not modified)
webapp_1     | Skipping 'admin/js/vendor/select2/i18n/dsb.js' (not modified)
webapp_1     | Skipping 'admin/js/vendor/select2/i18n/he.js' (not modified)
webapp_1     | Skipping 'admin/js/vendor/select2/i18n/gl.js' (not modified)
webapp_1     | Skipping 'admin/js/vendor/select2/i18n/lt.js' (not modified)
webapp_1     | Skipping 'admin/js/vendor/select2/i18n/nl.js' (not modified)
webapp_1     | Skipping 'admin/js/vendor/select2/i18n/th.js' (not modified)
webapp_1     | Skipping 'admin/js/vendor/select2/i18n/sr-Cyrl.js' (not modified)
webapp_1     | Skipping 'admin/js/vendor/select2/i18n/de.js' (not modified)
webapp_1     | Skipping 'admin/js/vendor/select2/i18n/pt-BR.js' (not modified)
webapp_1     | Skipping 'admin/js/vendor/select2/i18n/af.js' (not modified)
webapp_1     | Skipping 'admin/js/vendor/select2/i18n/tr.js' (not modified)
webapp_1     | Skipping 'admin/js/vendor/select2/i18n/sl.js' (not modified)
webapp_1     | Skipping 'admin/js/vendor/select2/i18n/mk.js' (not modified)
webapp_1     | Skipping 'admin/js/vendor/select2/i18n/sk.js' (not modified)
webapp_1     | Skipping 'admin/js/vendor/select2/i18n/km.js' (not modified)
webapp_1     | Skipping 'admin/js/vendor/select2/i18n/sq.js' (not modified)
webapp_1     | Skipping 'admin/js/vendor/select2/i18n/es.js' (not modified)
webapp_1     | Skipping 'admin/js/vendor/select2/i18n/hsb.js' (not modified)
webapp_1     | Skipping 'admin/js/vendor/select2/i18n/fi.js' (not modified)
webapp_1     | Skipping 'admin/js/vendor/select2/i18n/id.js' (not modified)
webapp_1     | Skipping 'admin/js/vendor/select2/i18n/tk.js' (not modified)
webapp_1     | Skipping 'admin/js/vendor/select2/i18n/pt.js' (not modified)
webapp_1     | Skipping 'admin/js/vendor/select2/i18n/en.js' (not modified)
webapp_1     | Skipping 'admin/js/vendor/select2/i18n/hu.js' (not modified)
webapp_1     | Skipping 'admin/js/vendor/select2/i18n/is.js' (not modified)
webapp_1     | Skipping 'admin/js/vendor/select2/i18n/bg.js' (not modified)
webapp_1     | Skipping 'admin/js/vendor/select2/i18n/hr.js' (not modified)
webapp_1     | Skipping 'admin/js/vendor/select2/i18n/sr.js' (not modified)
webapp_1     | Skipping 'admin/js/vendor/select2/i18n/ne.js' (not modified)
webapp_1     | Skipping 'admin/js/vendor/select2/i18n/ro.js' (not modified)
webapp_1     | Skipping 'admin/js/vendor/select2/i18n/ru.js' (not modified)
webapp_1     | Skipping 'admin/js/vendor/select2/i18n/az.js' (not modified)
webapp_1     | Skipping 'admin/js/vendor/select2/i18n/pl.js' (not modified)
webapp_1     | Skipping 'admin/js/vendor/select2/i18n/lv.js' (not modified)
webapp_1     | Skipping 'admin/js/vendor/select2/i18n/bn.js' (not modified)
webapp_1     | Skipping 'admin/js/vendor/select2/i18n/uk.js' (not modified)
webapp_1     | Skipping 'admin/js/vendor/select2/i18n/bs.js' (not modified)
webapp_1     | Skipping 'admin/js/vendor/select2/i18n/cs.js' (not modified)
webapp_1     | Skipping 'admin/js/vendor/select2/i18n/ar.js' (not modified)
webapp_1     | Skipping 'admin/js/vendor/select2/i18n/fr.js' (not modified)
webapp_1     | Skipping 'admin/js/vendor/select2/i18n/ka.js' (not modified)
webapp_1     | Skipping 'admin/js/vendor/select2/i18n/zh-CN.js' (not modified)
webapp_1     | Skipping 'admin/js/vendor/select2/i18n/el.js' (not modified)
webapp_1     | Skipping 'admin/js/vendor/select2/i18n/nb.js' (not modified)
webapp_1     | Skipping 'admin/js/vendor/select2/i18n/zh-TW.js' (not modified)
webapp_1     | Skipping 'admin/js/vendor/select2/i18n/ps.js' (not modified)
webapp_1     | Skipping 'admin/js/admin/RelatedObjectLookups.js' (not modified)
webapp_1     | Skipping 'admin/js/admin/DateTimeShortcuts.js' (not modified)
webapp_1     | Skipping 'admin/img/calendar-icons.svg' (not modified)
webapp_1     | Skipping 'admin/img/README.txt' (not modified)
webapp_1     | Skipping 'admin/img/icon-calendar.svg' (not modified)
webapp_1     | Skipping 'admin/img/search.svg' (not modified)
webapp_1     | Skipping 'admin/img/icon-unknown-alt.svg' (not modified)
webapp_1     | Skipping 'admin/img/icon-clock.svg' (not modified)
webapp_1     | Skipping 'admin/img/selector-icons.svg' (not modified)
webapp_1     | Skipping 'admin/img/icon-changelink.svg' (not modified)
webapp_1     | Skipping 'admin/img/icon-yes.svg' (not modified)
webapp_1     | Skipping 'admin/img/LICENSE' (not modified)
webapp_1     | Skipping 'admin/img/icon-alert.svg' (not modified)
webapp_1     | Skipping 'admin/img/icon-deletelink.svg' (not modified)
webapp_1     | Skipping 'admin/img/tooltag-add.svg' (not modified)
webapp_1     | Skipping 'admin/img/tooltag-arrowright.svg' (not modified)
webapp_1     | Skipping 'admin/img/sorting-icons.svg' (not modified)
webapp_1     | Skipping 'admin/img/inline-delete.svg' (not modified)
webapp_1     | Skipping 'admin/img/icon-no.svg' (not modified)
webapp_1     | Skipping 'admin/img/icon-unknown.svg' (not modified)
webapp_1     | Skipping 'admin/img/icon-addlink.svg' (not modified)
webapp_1     | Skipping 'admin/img/icon-viewlink.svg' (not modified)
webapp_1     | Skipping 'admin/img/gis/move_vertex_on.svg' (not modified)
webapp_1     | Skipping 'admin/img/gis/move_vertex_off.svg' (not modified)
webapp_1     | Skipping 'admin/css/changelists.css' (not modified)
webapp_1     | Skipping 'admin/css/login.css' (not modified)
webapp_1     | Skipping 'admin/css/dashboard.css' (not modified)
webapp_1     | Skipping 'admin/css/fonts.css' (not modified)
webapp_1     | Skipping 'admin/css/responsive_rtl.css' (not modified)
webapp_1     | Skipping 'admin/css/widgets.css' (not modified)
webapp_1     | Skipping 'admin/css/responsive.css' (not modified)
webapp_1     | Skipping 'admin/css/rtl.css' (not modified)
webapp_1     | Skipping 'admin/css/autocomplete.css' (not modified)
webapp_1     | Skipping 'admin/css/base.css' (not modified)
webapp_1     | Skipping 'admin/css/forms.css' (not modified)
webapp_1     | Skipping 'admin/css/vendor/select2/select2.min.css' (not modified)
webapp_1     | Skipping 'admin/css/vendor/select2/LICENSE-SELECT2.md' (not modified)
webapp_1     | Skipping 'admin/css/vendor/select2/select2.css' (not modified)
webapp_1     | 
webapp_1     | 0 static files copied to '/srv/starter/static', 130 unmodified.
webapp_1     | ==> Starting uWSGI ...
webapp_1     | *** Starting uWSGI 2.0.17.1 (64bit) on [Fri Mar 20 00:50:56 2020] ***
webapp_1     | compiled with version: 8.3.0 on 19 March 2020 23:41:29
webapp_1     | os: Linux-4.19.76-linuxkit #1 SMP Thu Oct 17 19:31:58 UTC 2019
webapp_1     | nodename: 4eb039cc2359
webapp_1     | machine: x86_64
webapp_1     | clock source: unix
webapp_1     | pcre jit disabled
webapp_1     | detected number of CPU cores: 4
webapp_1     | current working directory: /
webapp_1     | detected binary path: /usr/local/bin/uwsgi
webapp_1     | uWSGI running as root, you can use --uid/--gid/--chroot options
webapp_1     | *** WARNING: you are running uWSGI as root !!! (use the --uid flag) *** 
webapp_1     | *** WARNING: you are running uWSGI without its master process manager ***
webapp_1     | your memory page size is 4096 bytes
webapp_1     | detected max file descriptor number: 1048576
webapp_1     | *** starting uWSGI Emperor ***
webapp_1     | *** has_emperor mode detected (fd: 5) ***
webapp_1     | [uWSGI] getting INI configuration from /etc/uwsgi/django-uwsgi.ini
webapp_1     | *** Starting uWSGI 2.0.17.1 (64bit) on [Fri Mar 20 00:50:57 2020] ***
webapp_1     | compiled with version: 8.3.0 on 19 March 2020 23:41:29
webapp_1     | os: Linux-4.19.76-linuxkit #1 SMP Thu Oct 17 19:31:58 UTC 2019
webapp_1     | nodename: 4eb039cc2359
webapp_1     | machine: x86_64
webapp_1     | clock source: unix
webapp_1     | pcre jit disabled
webapp_1     | detected number of CPU cores: 4
webapp_1     | current working directory: /
webapp_1     | detected binary path: /usr/local/bin/uwsgi
webapp_1     | setgid() to 102
webapp_1     | setuid() to 101
webapp_1     | chdir() to /srv/starter/
webapp_1     | your memory page size is 4096 bytes
webapp_1     |  *** WARNING: you have enabled harakiri without post buffering. Slow upload could be rejected on post-unbuffered webservers *** 
webapp_1     | detected max file descriptor number: 1048576
webapp_1     | lock engine: pthread robust mutexes
webapp_1     | thunder lock: disabled (you can enable it with --thunder-lock)
webapp_1     | uwsgi socket 0 bound to TCP address :8000 fd 3
webapp_1     | Python version: 3.7.7 (default, Mar 11 2020, 00:27:03)  [GCC 8.3.0]
webapp_1     | Python main interpreter initialized at 0x55da2c534200
webapp_1     | python threads support enabled
webapp_1     | your server socket listen backlog is limited to 100 connections
webapp_1     | your mercy for graceful operations on workers is 60 seconds
webapp_1     | mapped 1315008 bytes (1284 KB) for 64 cores
webapp_1     | *** Operational MODE: preforking+threaded ***
webapp_1     | *** uWSGI is running in multiple interpreter mode ***
webapp_1     | spawned uWSGI master process (pid: 11)
webapp_1     | Fri Mar 20 00:50:57 2020 - [emperor] vassal /etc/uwsgi/django-uwsgi.ini has been spawned
webapp_1     | spawned uWSGI worker 1 (pid: 12, cores: 8)
webapp_1     | spawned uWSGI worker 2 (pid: 13, cores: 8)
webapp_1     | spawned uWSGI worker 3 (pid: 14, cores: 8)
webapp_1     | spawned uWSGI worker 4 (pid: 15, cores: 8)
webapp_1     | spawned uWSGI worker 5 (pid: 16, cores: 8)
webapp_1     | spawned uWSGI worker 6 (pid: 17, cores: 8)
webapp_1     | spawned uWSGI worker 7 (pid: 18, cores: 8)
webapp_1     | spawned uWSGI worker 8 (pid: 19, cores: 8)
webapp_1     | unable to stat() /etc/uwsgi/reload-uwsgi.ini, events will be triggered as soon as the file is created
webapp_1     | ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'starter'
webapp_1     | unable to load app 0 (mountpoint='') (callable not found or import error)
webapp_1     | *** no app loaded. going in full dynamic mode ***
webapp_1     | ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'starter'
webapp_1     | unable to load app 0 (mountpoint='') (callable not found or import error)
webapp_1     | *** no app loaded. going in full dynamic mode ***
webapp_1     | ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'starter'
webapp_1     | unable to load app 0 (mountpoint='') (callable not found or import error)
webapp_1     | *** no app loaded. going in full dynamic mode ***
webapp_1     | ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'starter'
webapp_1     | unable to load app 0 (mountpoint='') (callable not found or import error)
webapp_1     | *** no app loaded. going in full dynamic mode ***
webapp_1     | ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'starter'
webapp_1     | unable to load app 0 (mountpoint='') (callable not found or import error)
webapp_1     | *** no app loaded. going in full dynamic mode ***
webapp_1     | Fri Mar 20 00:50:57 2020 - [emperor] vassal /etc/uwsgi/django-uwsgi.ini is ready to accept requests
webapp_1     | ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'starter'
webapp_1     | unable to load app 0 (mountpoint='') (callable not found or import error)
webapp_1     | *** no app loaded. going in full dynamic mode ***
webapp_1     | ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'starter'
webapp_1     | unable to load app 0 (mountpoint='') (callable not found or import error)
webapp_1     | *** no app loaded. going in full dynamic mode ***
webapp_1     | ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'starter'
webapp_1     | unable to load app 0 (mountpoint='') (callable not found or import error)
webapp_1     | *** no app loaded. going in full dynamic mode ***
```

It appears as if the problem could be here:

```
# the base directory (full path)
chdir = /srv/$(DJANGO_PROJECT_NAME)/

# Django's wsgi file (path starting from chdir/)
module = $(DJANGO_PROJECT_NAME).wsgi:application
```

Here's the thing: I created the project without docker, called `covidoff`, and asked this guy to do the Docker integration. It looks like `DJANGO_PROJECT_NAME` is `starter`. Is that wrong?

Answer (score 1):

> unable to load app 0 (mountpoint='') (callable not found or import error)

This seems to be your problem. Maybe try focusing on getting uWSGI to be able to find your code?

Answer (score 1):

Try to remove the :application here in your django-uwsgi.ini file

```
# Django's wsgi file (path starting from chdir/)
module = $(DJANGO_PROJECT_NAME).wsgi:application
```

Comment: Got the same result :\

Answer (score 1):

Turns out it as a conflict with names. I created the project as `covidoff`, but the Docker integration was calling it `starter`. Moved everything occurrence of `starter` to `covidoff` and it worked.